# How to parse the com.android.calllogbackup file

Tags: android, deserialization, backup, calllog

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1WrP.png)
as the title says，I have an Android calllog backup file, but I don't know the deserialization rules, does anyone know how to parse the file

As shown in the picture, the opened format is similar to the above

Parse the file into json format